# removing style and script tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Im using [SWIPE](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe) to display a div slideshow.

SWIPE standard set up:

```
 <div id='slider' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But my code has a unfortunate addition which cause the SWIPE not to function...

```
 <div id='slider' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
   <script></script>
   <style></style>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The script and style tags cause it to not work....

Why is there a script and style tag you must be thinking...

I have a script that post data my page

```
 <script src="js.php?id=22235"></script>
```

this outputs something like

```
   <style type="text/css"></style>
   <div id='Gallery'>

   <div class="Details">
   <img src="555.jpg">
   <div class="Price">$5</div>
   </div>

   <div class="Details">
   <img src="111.jpg">
   <div class="Price">$1</div>
   </div>

   </div>
```

So my actually code looks like this prior to opening it up in a browser

```
 <div id='slider' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
 <script src="js.php?id=22235"></script>
 </div>
</div>
```

So now what have i tried ... well i used jquery to remove the tags after the content is in place but, this seems to be too late...and swipe has already freaked out on me

```
 $('.swipe-wrap style').remove();
```

ahh beyond this i started to create another page to dump the contents in then i was going to use some php parse just the div section and i got to think there has to be a better way...So im here

Thanks,
JT

Comment: You have to first do things with jquery and then dynamically load script swipe script through getScript that may resolve the issue

Comment: place your jquery statement before your swipe initialization statement, and you should be good to go. If not, wrap both of them in a `window.onload` wrapper to ensure your php script has returned its values before you initialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the script is executed once it is loaded (if there is some top-level code) or when it is called the first time after it has been loaded. Only after the script executes, you can remove the style tag.

If you have access to the script, you could change it in a way that it doesn't add the style element anymore. If you don't have access (I'll assume that), you can follow this way:

**Adding event listener to DOM changes**

First use jQuery to add an eventlistener for a DOM modification event. Such an event would be DOMNodeInserted. You attach the eventlistener to an element that is there definitely. It could look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.swipe-wrap').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'style', function(event) {
        var target = $(event.currentTarget);
        target.remove();
        $('.swipe-wrap script').remove();
        loadSWIPE();
    });
});
```

That way you remove each style element, once it has been added to the DOM.

**Ensure that SWIPE is loaded after this cleanup**

Load the SWIPE script in a function that gets called when a style element is removed (as above). Inside the function you check how many style elements below the `.swipe-wrap` element are existing and only if there is none, the SWIPE script gets loaded.

```
function loadSWIPE() {
    var length = $('#mySwipe style').length;
    if (length == 0) {
        var url = "swipe.js";
        $.getScript(url, function() {
            var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
            window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {});
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Added removal of the script tag for the PHP script.

Comment: Worked just as you said it would...one small issue! I also need to delete the script tag. How would you do this? Remove it when the style tag is removed ?

Comment: Thank you my friend! ahhh life saver :)

Comment: ok almost working `$.getScript("swipe.js");` is not acceptable as a replacement for `<script src='swipe.js'></script>`  when i try to load using getscript it does not work